# Regarding the common zeros of the system of equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Consider the following two systems of n homogeneous polynomials in n variables of degree $d$ with complex coefficients:

**System 1 ($S_1$):**

$f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$\vdots$

$f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$ and

**System 2 ($S_2$):**

$x_1 f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$x_2 f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$\vdots$

$x_n f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$.

**System 3 ($S_3$):**

$x_1^2 f_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$x_2^2 f_2(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$,

$\vdots$

$x_n^2 f_n(x_1,\dots,x_n) = 0$.

I am interested in understanding the relation between the zeros of the systems 1, 2 and 3. Every solution of $S_1$ is also a solution of $S_2$ and so on.

I have the following question:

1. How the multiplicities of the solutions of the above-given systems are related?

Thanks for your time and consideration. Have a good day.

Comment: If you don't care about multiplicity (2) and (3) are equivalent, no? Also if you fix a subset J of [n], and consider the reduced system x_i=0 for i in J, and f_i=0 for i in [n]\J, the union of the solutions for all J cover all solutions of (2).

Comment: @PietroMajer Actually, I want to understand the multiplicities :) . I have edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: In Pietro's notation, the solutions of $S_3$ for any $J$ have scheme length multiplied by $2^{|J|}$ (relative to their length in $S_2$). Have you considered a simple example such as $x-1=y-1=0$; $x(x-1)=y(y-1)=0$; $x^2(x-1)=y^2(y-1)=0$. Here the four solution points support schemes of lengths 1,0,0,0; then 1,1,1,1; then 1,2,2,4.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Please explain "scheme length" and why it gets multiplied by $2^{|J|}$. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you tell me. What is the multiplicity of $x=y=0$? Of $x=y^2=0$? Of $x^2=y^2=0$?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Multiplicity of (x,y)=(0,0)?

Comment: These are good questions but I think better for [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ZachTeitler Please explain Here the four solution points support schemes of lengths 1,0,0,0; then 1,1,1,1; then 1,2,2,4 in your previous comment.

Comment: After all, that's more a problem of elementary logic or elementary set algebra, than algebraic geometry.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have time to teach what are schemes or other basic things in algebraic geometry. I only mentioned schemes because I assumed you knew some basic things if you were asking these questions.